Bind error after update: directory '/var/named' is not writable - But no writing is necessary!
After upgrading a CentOS 7 server to AlmaLinux 9, and BIND along with it, I receive a new error message without changing (bind/named) configuration files:
systemctl status named
× named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-07-29 17:21:47 UTC; 19min ago
    Process: 948 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 949 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 33ms

Jul 29 17:21:47 ns42.example.org named[950]: directory '/var/named' is not writable
Jul 29 17:21:47 ns42.example.org named[950]: /etc/named.conf:22: parsing failed: permission denied
Jul 29 17:21:47 ns42.example.org loading configuration: permission denied
Jul 29 17:21:47 ns42.example.org exiting (due to fatal error)

Why would (this newer version of) named need to write its zone files?
This is a non-recursive secondary/backup name server and this instance of BIND/named is not to change zones.
So I suppose the question could be: How can I tell BIND not to try to write into its zone directory and not to complain about not being able to?
Bind version is bind-9.16.23-18.el9_4.1.x86_64
EDIT:
Out of curiosity I temporarily made the folder writable by the named group and started the service.  This is what it wrote:
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named  1045 Jul 29 17:51 /var/named/localhost_resolver.mkeys.jnl
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named  1045 Jul 29 17:51 /var/named/external.mkeys.jnl
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named  1045 Jul 29 17:51 /var/named/internal.mkeys.jnl
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named   821 Jul 29 17:52 /var/named/internal.mkeys
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named   821 Jul 29 17:52 /var/named/external.mkeys
-rw-r--r--. 1 named named   821 Jul 29 17:52 /var/named/localhost_resolver.mkeys

So, these are some type of journal files.  How can disable writing these journal entries as the zones are read-only anyway?

I've always configured Bind with a writable working directory. Bind reference (https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) says "<...>For this reason, among others, the working directory should be always be writable by named. <...>" so I guess it's by design, regardless of operation mode.

@Edward Thanks. Perhaps these temporary files could be written elsewhere? In my setup they are not needed and security hardening principles say a daemon cannot be allowed change its own configuration.

If you are running SELinux in enforced mode, bind can't change it's own config even when it's writable because the named_t domain isn't allowed write on named_conf_t file contexts: sesearch --allow -s named_t -t named_conf_t -c file shows readonly access.
But then you need to be sure that your config files have the named_conf_t context. By default, that should be true.

Good point.  SELinux is set to enforcing but could named by accident/hack write zone files (db)?  Those are not strictly config files but I want to make sure these are not changed or deleted.
